# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre la apertura PHP (<?php ?>) y (<? ?>)?

Tags: php, html

Amigos, se que la pregunta suena como tonta, eso que llevo estudiando php poco mas de 1 año y me surgió esta duda al usar la apertura `<? ?>` y funciona de igual manera, pero de seguro desconozco el por qué, ¿alguien mas experto me puede decir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando PHP analiza un fichero, busca las etiquetas de apertura y cierre, que son `<?php y ?>`, y que indican a PHP dónde empezar y finalizar la interpretación del código. Este mecanismo permite embeber a PHP en todo tipo de documentos, ya que todo lo que esté fuera de las etiquetas de apertura y cierre de PHP será ignorado por el analizador.

PHP también permite la etiqueta de apertura abreviada `<?` (la cual está desaconsejada debido a que sólo está disponible si se habilita con la directiva short_open_tag del fichero de configuración `php.ini`, o si PHP se configuró con la opción `--enable-short-tags` ).

Acá te dejo la información completa:

[Etiquetas de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: buena respuesta, solo cambiaria la parte que el analizador lo ignora, sino explicaria que es un bypass, como lo escribiste va al fichero de salida.

Answer (score 2):

Son lo mismo, solo que una es la versión larga y otra la versión corta.

Se puede habilitar en *php.ini* mediante la directiva de configuración `short_open_tag`

Puedes ver su explicación en la documentación de PHP: [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)  y [Etiquetas de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

En general se recomienda no usar los tags cortos, porque dependes de que esten habilitados en la configuración (y no todos los proveedores te permiten hacer cambios a la configuración), y porque tener los tags completos, te permiten ver claramente cuando entras a PHP.